# What is the value of the constant in the time geodesic for the Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity

For the geodesics in Schwarzschild space, I think the derivative of *component* time with respect to *proper* time is some constant (k) divided by (1-r_s/r). i.e., 1.0 minus the black hole horizon radius (r_s) divided by the radial location (r).
So (k) is dimensionless? And its value at infinity (for Minkowski metric) is 1.0? Is (k) ever equal to anything **other** than 1.0 (in Schwarzschild space)?

Comment: The units of both $t$ and $\tau$ are seconds so $dt/d\tau$ is dimensionless. The value of $dt/d\tau$ will depend on the velocity of the object as well as its position, so there is no simple answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to stipulate that I am asking about the situation for zero radial velocity. Would constant (k) then always be 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Schwarzschild metric is:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2 dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}+r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 \tag{1} $$

If the observer near the black hole is stationary in space they are only moving in time so $dr = d\theta = d\phi = 0$. Only $dt$ and $d\tau$ are non-zero i.e. the observer is moving only in the time direction. Substituting this into equation (1) we get:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2 dt^2 \tag{2} $$

Then use $ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2$ and equation (2) becomes:

$$ -c^2 d\tau^2 = -\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2 dt^2 \tag{2} $$

and a quick rearrangement later we get:

$$ \frac{dt}{d\tau} = \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1/2} $$

So your constant $k$ is always equal to one.